# How to make a specific button disappear permanently on React.js?

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, components, state

I am trying to make a button disappear after clicking so that even if I go to a different component(different pages) it will stay that way.

Here is the code:

```js
<Button
  className="but"
  variant="primary"
  onClick={(e) => {
    const tr = {
      id: info.track.track_id,
      trackName: info.track.track_name,
      artistName: info.track.artist_name,
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(tr),
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('blog added');
    });
  }}
  style={{ marginLeft: '6px' }}
>
  Mark
</Button>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to manage a display of the `button` in a global state or handle it from the button's parent component.

Like this:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      {showButton && (
        <Button
          className="but"
          variant="primary"
          onClick={(e) => {
            const tr = {
              id: info.track.track_id,
              trackName: info.track.track_name,
              artistName: info.track.artist_name,
            };

            fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
              body: JSON.stringify(tr),
            }).then(() => {
              console.log('blog added');
              setShowButton(false)
            });
          }}
          style={{ marginLeft: '6px' }}
        >
          Mark
        </Button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

To manage state on a global level you can use the [`React.Context`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API

First, create the ButtonContext in your root app like this

```js
const ButtonContext = React.createContext({
  showButton: true,
  setShowButton: (show) => {}
});
```

Wrap it around your root `App` and pass the value of `showButton` as `true` using the `useState` hook

```js
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(true);

<ButtonContext.Provider value={{ showButton, setShowButton }}>
  <App />
</ButtonContext.Provider>
```

Then use it in your `Button`'s `ParentComponent` like this

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {
  const {showButton, setShowButton} = useContext(ButtonContext);

  return (
    <>
      {showButton && (
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            // do your click stuff and
            // reset the showButton context value
            setShowButton(false)
           }
          }
        >
        </Button>)}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: the button is inside a map so there are multiple buttons. So your answer is gonna affect all the buttons instead of the clicked one. Right?

Comment: If it's in a map and you want to hide only the clicked button, then it's a different implementation.

Comment: I can update my answer if that is what you're looking for?

Comment: Meanwhile share more of the Parent Component code where the button is called

Comment: I just posted a new answer different from this one. Check it out and let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

use can use state to hid the button something like

```
{ showButton && (
   < Button className="but" variant="primary" onClick={(e)=>{
const tr={id:info.track.track_id,trackName:info.track.track_name,artistName:info.track.artist_name}

fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs',{
 method:'POST',
 headers:{ "Content-Type": "application/json"},
 body: JSON.stringify(tr)
 } ).then(()=>{
  console.log("blog added");
    setShowButton(false);
 });
            }} style={{ marginLeft:"6px" }}>Mark</Button>
)}
```

Comment: I already tried but it hides all the buttons.

Comment: hmm maybe try adding a css class for display: none; to the specific buttons that need hidden and then toggle the class when you need to switch them? How do you know which buttons in the map need to be shown and which don't?

Comment: I have multiple cards and each card has a button and if I click on the button the card goes to favorite list. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide it permanently for a user then you have to register that user activity somewhere in the backend. Then send a http request so you can get data if the user can perform that activity again or not. Depending in the response you set some state and then from that state you can hide/show the button.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/can-user-perform-activity-again')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.yes){
          setShowButton(true)
        } 
        if(response.no){
          setShowButton(false);
        }
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {showButton && <button>Vote</button>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: the button is inside a map so there are multiple buttons. How can I set the state so it recognize the specific button??

Comment: What are those buttons for?

Comment: I have multiple cards and each card has a button and if I click on the button the card goes to favorite list. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Button` is being rendered within a map, you can create a custom button component from your existing button that manages the `hide` state and returns the actual `Button` or `null`.

Custom button should look something like this:

```js
const CustomButton = ({ info }) => {
  const [hide, setHide] = useState(false);

  return hide ? (
    <Button
      className="but"
      variant="primary"
      onClick={(e) => {
        const tr = {
          id: info.track.track_id,
          trackName: info.track.track_name,
          artistName: info.track.artist_name,
        };

        fetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
          body: JSON.stringify(tr),
        }).then(() => {
          console.log('blog added');
          setHide(false);
        });
      }}
      style={{ marginLeft: '6px' }}
    >
      Mark
    </Button>
  ) : null;
};
```

And you can use it within your `.map()` and pass `info` as `props` to it.

like this:

```js
{data.map((info) => (
  <CustomButton
    key={info.track.track_id}
    info={info}
  />)
)}
```

Comment: it kinda worked but when i go to different page the button comes back

Comment: Then use the `React.Context` API to manage the state globally so that when you navigate to a different component it doesn't come back. Check my other answer to see how to do that.